# Stop direct execute php code without button click

Tags: php, javascript, buttonclick

I need to let the code below to stop directly execute the code without button click. I want the function to run when button is click on it. Thanks for the help

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript">
{
function popup() {
<?php echo shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh') ?>;
}
}    
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="popup">




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to make a form or change something in url like `window.location` and check vars. You cannot mix Javascript with PHP like that

`script.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function popup(){
        window.location = 'script.php?run=shell';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="popup">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'shell')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that both cannot be mix together. but is there anyway to execute the shell file as i need to use php as well.

and the sh file is not execute with the code provided. thanks for reply

Comment: I had a `!` wrongly there, modified. And you should know you cannot execute a `shell` script if you don't have permissions.

Comment: i have dome all the permission stuff d. i try only php can be execute. but i need use button click so this is the problem i get when use javascript

Comment: window.location = 'script.php?run=shell';

Answer (score 0):

your html is invalid. your `</script>` tag should be before the `</head>` tag

if you really want to execute it only when you press the button then you should consider using ajax or to use a `<form>`

Comment: sorry. copy and paste wrongly. but even put in correct place still will auto execute the script without me pressing the button

Answer (score 0):

`alert('<?php echo shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh') ; ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ajax-request, for example, with jquery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript">
            {
                function popup() {
                    $.post('someScript.php');
                }
            }    
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="popup">
    </body>
</html>
```

In "someScript.php" you can put command

```
shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh');
```